# colspan and rowspan in css 2.1?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to use CSS level 2.1 to achieve the same effect as XHTML 1.0 does with the attributes `rowspan` and `colspan`, but using only CSS.

I tried to figure out a way and did some research, but couldn't find one. I don't want to use CSS level 2 or CSS3.

Can anyone can point me to some source for all the CSS level 2.1 specifications, or tell me what they use for CSS level 2.1 to emulate rowspan/colspan?

Comment: @phihag sorry I didn't see that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do that in CSS2.1 however in CSS3 you can use [multi-columns](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/)

So you could define your "table" similar to:

```
div { column-count: 2; column-width: 200px; }
```

and then do a columns span with

```
div2 { column-span: all; }
```

Comment: Thanks I will take this as an references for my future project.... ^_^